# They wouldn't/won't come here if they didn't/don't like this place

Tags: sentence-meaning, tense, conditional-constructions

What's the difference in meaning between:

> They wouldn't come here if they didn't like this place.
>
> They won't come here if they don't like this place.

Answer (score 1):

> They wouldn't come here if they didn't like this place.

Means they do come here because they like this place.

> They won't come here if they don't like this place.

Means they are thinking about coming here, but could be deterred by how they feel about this place.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding,

> They wouldn't come here if they didn't like this place.

It's past tense. They have already came and gone.

The other sentence is people haven't come yet. The event has not taken place yet.